# I am trying to replace the blacked out cells in the below table with another image with Python OpenCV. How can I do this?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following code but for some reason my code isn't detecting the black regions. I thought setting the threshold to 0.5 would allow it to limit only to the black regions but I am not having success with this. Below is the image with the blacked out spots and then my image I want to replace the blacked out areas with. Any idea how I can limit the contour detection to just the blacked out areas? I want to do this for any version of this exact table that may have only 1 column of blacked out cells or 2 or however many there area.

[image]

[image]

```
orig_img = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/15127/Downloads/download (1) (1).png')

cv2.imshow('image', orig_img)

# Define the threshold for identifying blacked-out areas
thresh = 0.5

replacement_img = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/15127/Downloads/tablereplace.png')

# Convert the original image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(orig_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the grayscale image to identify blacked-out areas
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Find contours around the blacked-out areas in the mask
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Loop over the contours and draw rectangles around the blacked-out areas in the original image
for contour in contours:
    # Get the bounding box of the blacked-out area
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(orig_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # Draw a red rectangle around the blacked-out area in the original image
    if orig_img[y:y + h, x:x + w].shape[0] == 104 and x * w * y > 100000:
        replacement_roi = cv2.resize(replacement_img, dsize=(w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        orig_img[y:y + h, x:x + w] = replacement_roi
        
cv2.imshow('image', orig_img)
```

I tried using the above code to detect the contours but it doesn't seem to work to limit to only the blacked out regions.

Comment: You said "I want to replace the blacked out areas with", but did not finish your sentence. What do you want to fill the black with?

Comment: The other image I have included in the post.   I'm trying to replace the blacked out parts with cells that say N/A

Comment: make mask for "black", "open" morphology operation to erase the text and grid lines from the mask, then you've got your connected components you can deal with. like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RKEs.png

Comment: or: how about you tell us what this is from? is it a screenshot? a screenshot of? a Word document? a web page? you can edit both of those **without** all this extra work.

Answer (score 4):

The main issue is that the black lines of the table connect the black rectangles, and form one large contour.

For deleting the lines we may apply [morphological opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_(morphology)) operations to the mask.
Apply opening in the vertical direction for removing the horizontal lines, and then apply opening in the horizontal direction for removing the vertical lines:

```
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5, 1), np.uint8))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((1, 5), np.uint8))
```

We may also have to change the condition `if orig_img[y:y + h, x:x + w].shape[0] == 104 and x * w * y > 100000` to something like `if w * h > 1000:`.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#orig_img = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/15127/Downloads/download (1) (1).png')
orig_img = cv2.imread('orig_image.png')
#cv2.imshow('image', orig_img)

# Define the threshold for identifying blacked-out areas
thresh = 0.5

#replacement_img = cv2.imread(r'C:/Users/15127/Downloads/tablereplace.png')
replacement_img = cv2.imread('tablereplace.png')

# Convert the original image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(orig_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the grayscale image to identify blacked-out areas
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Apply opening in the vertical direction and then in the horizontal direction - erasing the lines that connects the contours
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5, 1), np.uint8))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((1, 5), np.uint8))

mask_img = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Find contours around the blacked-out areas in the mask
#contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Have contours inside contours, use RETR_TREE (RETR_EXTERNAL finds only the most outer contour) - not needed after opening

# Loop over the contours and draw rectangles around the blacked-out areas in the original image
for contour in contours:
    # Get the bounding box of the blacked-out area
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)    
    # Draw a red rectangle around the blacked-out area in the original image
    #if orig_img[y:y + h, x:x + w].shape[0] == 104 and x * w * y > 100000:
    if w * h > 1000:
        cv2.rectangle(mask_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        replacement_roi = cv2.resize(replacement_img, dsize=(w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        orig_img[y:y + h, x:x + w] = replacement_roi
        cv2.rectangle(orig_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        
cv2.imshow('image', orig_img)
cv2.imshow('mask_img', mask_img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`mask` after opening operations:
[image]

`orig_img` output:
[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Didn't even think of removing the black lines before.